# Simple Numpy 2-D matrix and meshgrid - ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I'm new to Python, and this task is probably simple, but I'm just not getting it.  I'm trying to model light transmission through a 2-D aperture using a grid: if light is transmitted, the grid-element is 1; if not, then 0.

I'm having trouble when iterating through the 2-D matrix.  I think there is an issue when comparing an element of the numpy array to the scalar value, especially because two conditions must be met.  I tried a.any() and a.all(), &, and np.logical_and(), but I can't seem to get them to work.

```
def make_object(x,y,a,b):
    f = np.zeros((len(x),len(y)))

    if np.abs(x) < (a/2.0):
        if np.abs(y) < (b/2.0):
            f[x][y] = 1.0
    return f


a = 6.0  # Width of slit
b = 6.0  # Height of slit
N = 20.0
x = np.linspace(-10.0,10.0,N)
y = np.linspace(-10.0,10.0,N)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

z = make_object(X,Y,a,b)
print z
```

I get this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-fef282d4a308> in <module>()
     29 x,y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
     30 
---> 31 z = make_object(x,y,a,b)
     32 
     33 

<ipython-input-13-fef282d4a308> in make_object(x, y, a, b)
      8     f = np.zeros((len(x),len(y)))
      9 
---> 10     if np.abs(x) < (a/2.0):
     11         if np.abs(y) < (b/2.0):
     12             f[x][y] = 1.0

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit: Code used previously without vectorization**

```
for i, xi in enumerate(x):
    for j, yj in enumerate(y):
        if np.abs(xi) < a/2:
            if np.abs(yj) < b/2:
                f[i][j] = 1.0
```

Comment: What do you want to do with `np.abs(x) < (a/2.0)` ?

Comment: @AnandSKumar if the element is less than (a/2.0) (the slit width) and less than (b/2.0) (the slit height), set the element to 1.0

Comment: x is a matrix of shape - `(20,20)` and y also same shape. what do you mean element is less than something?

Comment: @AnandSKumar Hmm, I guess that's where I'm running into confusion.  If x and y are on Cartesian axes, if a point on x is less than slit width, it would transmit.  I wanted to model this on a numpy grid.

Comment: See all the 'related' questions on the side bar - with the same ValueError in the subject line?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is x and y are arrays, not individual elements. Heres what your code evaluates to before it reaches an error:

```
if array([True, False, ... ]):
```

To Python, evaluating whether an entire array is True or False makes no sense. If you want to use if statements, you have to iterate through the array and check if individual elements are less than the cutoff rather than entire arrays.

```
for i in range(f.shape[0]):
    for j in range(f.shape[1]):
        if x[i][j] < a/2:
           if y[i][j] < b/2:
                f[i][j] = 1
```

However, since you are using NumPy, you do not need if statements and can take advantage of [vectorization](http://quantess.net/2013/09/30/vectorization-magic-for-your-computations/) and solve your problem in a single line.

```
f[ np.logical_and(np.abs(x) < a/2.0,  np.abs(y) < b/2.0) ] = 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  At first, I use the code above (*see edit*), iterating through each element.
    
As you mentioned, I want to try to vectorize it instead of using "for" loops, so I attempted to use np.meshgrid.  So then, np.logical_and is relevant with np.meshgrid?  I am worried that I won't be able to extend my function to 3-D.

Comment: I am not familiar with np.meshgrid, but the vectorized version of the code should work in any number of dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Comparison operators acting on numpy arrays operate on a element-wise basis, i.e.

`array([0, 0, 0, 3]) > 2` will produce `array([False, False, False, True])`

Rohanp's solution will work, but I'd also suggest the useful numpy function [`where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), which would be used in one of two ways.

**Option 1: insert values to create z directly**

```
truevals = numpy.ones_like(X) #(or = numpy.zeros_like(X) + desired_value)
falsevals = numpy.zeros_like(X)
z = numpy.where((np.abs(X) < 6.0) & (np.abs(Y) < 6.0), truevals, falsevals)
```

note the use of & rather than "and"!

**Option 2: return indices where conditions are true**

This would be more useful if you don't want to simply insert one value or another, but perhaps do some more complex analysis only on those positions which evaluate as true, and ignore the rest

```
indices = numpy.where((np.abs(X) < 6.0) & (np.abs(Y) < 6.0))
z = numpy.zeros_like(X)
for i, j in zip(*indices):
    z[i][j] = 5*(i+j) # for example
```

Comment: Thanks!  Go to know about another solution.